# Sinusoidal Balls Animated CSS3

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm right now trying to make a Sinusoidal wave with three balls, each ball is a div. I'm using CSS3 keyframes to create the animation. Sadly the balls seem to getting timed with random offsets. I would like to stay way from JS, however, if necessary I understand.

My current JS Fiddle is: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/90zugb5z/3/)

HTML Structure:

```
<div id="background">
  <div id="ball_1" class="ball"></div>
  <div id="ball_2" class="ball"></div>
  <div id="ball_3" class="ball"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes color_change {
    0%   {background-color: red;}
    25%  {background-color: yellow;}
    50%  {background-color: orange;}
    75%  {background-color: green;}
    100% {background-color: blue;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
    0%   {transform: translateY(0px);}
    50% {transform: translateY(50px);}
    100%{transform: translateY(0px);}
}

#background{
    background-color: #000;
    height: 100px;
}

.ball{
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 35px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    display: inline-block;   
}

#ball_1{
    -webkit-animation: bounce 4s infinite;
}
#ball_2{
    -webkit-animation: bounce 3.5s infinite;
}
#ball_3{
    -webkit-animation: bounce 3s infinite;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing the effects of the easing calculation, which is defaulted to `ease`.  If you explicitly tell it to not use that easing for the animation, you'll see it behave how you expect it to.

## [Example fiddle here with no easing](http://jsfiddle.net/90zugb5z/4/)

With this being the substantive change to your CSS:

```
#ball_1{
    -webkit-animation: bounce 4s linear infinite; /* Added linear */
}
#ball_2{
    -webkit-animation: bounce 3.5s linear infinite; /* Added linear */
}
#ball_3{
    -webkit-animation: bounce 3s linear infinite; /* Added linear */
}
```

---

## Edit: animation-delay property

So reading further it looks like what you're looking for might be more of a delay property.  Luckily for you, there's a solution to that too.

## [Example fiddle with a half second delay before animation start](http://jsfiddle.net/90zugb5z/5/)

And here's the CSS for that:

```
#ball_1{
    -webkit-animation: bounce 4s 0s linear infinite;
    animation: bounce 4s 0s linear infinite;
}
#ball_2{
    -webkit-animation: bounce 4s 0.5s linear infinite;
    animation: bounce 4s 0.5s linear infinite;
}
#ball_3{
    -webkit-animation: bounce 4s 1s linear infinite;
    animation: bounce 4s 1s linear infinite;
}
```

That second number in the animation shorthand is the `delay` property.  If you're not using shorthand, you can set it individually by using `animation-delay`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! I'm still new to CSS3 Animations; so, this is great information!